# RPI Tracking disk usage - hidden usage

Tags: raspberry-pi, disk-usage

I am using Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS (UNIX based) and trying to find out where all my disk space has gone. Whatever disk usage analyser tool I tried, nothing showed the correct result.

Result of `df -h` shows that 204 GB of 219 GB is used:
[image]

But when I try du command on every single directory in the root folder, it sums up to a few gigabytes.

I tried to install ncdu, but the results is the same, it shows that only about 15 GB is used: `sudo ncdu -rx /`
[image]

I would be grateful for any tips/ideas how to analyse this.
My first thought was about docker cache, but I cleared everything (images, containers, volumes etc.) and not with much difference.

Thanks in advance.